# Jumps on a Plot animation

Tags: plotting, animation

The following code:

```
 Table[
  Plot[Sin[a], {a, 0, i}, PlotRange -> {{i - 3600, i}, {-1, 1}}, 
   ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 0.2, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {{Style["SOME TEXT - m", 13], 
      None}, {Style["Time - s", 13], Style["THE TITLE", 13, Bold]}}, 
   Axes -> False],
  {i, 1, 10000, 100}
  ]
```

Generates jumpy labels, ticks and frames:

[image]

How can I get a less vibrating plot (not referring to the plotted line itself...)

**EDIT:**

The following is closer to my real case, and `ImagePadding` doesn't work:

```
Dynamic@ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[a], {a, i - 3600, i}], 
  PlotRange -> {{i - 3600, i}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 800, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.2, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["Something", 13], 
     None}, {Style["Time - s", 13], Style["SOMETHING", 13, Bold]}}, 
  Axes -> False, ImagePadding -> 50]
Do[Pause[0.1]; i = a, {a, 10, 1000000}]
```

Comment: The shortest solution ever... wait for it... `ImagePadding -> 50` :)

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, it works on this example, but not on my real test. Give me some minutes try to choose a better test...

Comment: I have faced this problem (the second one), with one pixel jumping. Bad alignment of objets was driving me crazy. I have failed trying to fix this. Notice that for notebook magnification different than 100% left ticks are standing still, in my case at least.

Comment: What version are you using?  I have V9.0.1 (Mac) and in the second example the labels, vertical ticks and frame are still.

Comment: You may find it less annoying with `GridLines-> None`and `Do[Pause[0.01]; i = a, {a, 10, 1000000, 1}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 V9.0.1 (Windows). So, it is OS dependent. Should it be reported?

Comment: I suppose so.  I just checked with `Export` and still no jumpiness.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be an approach:

```
Dynamic@Grid[{{"", 
 Style["THE TITLE", Bold, Red, 14]}, {Style[
 Rotate[Text["SOME TEXT"], 90 Degree], Bold, Darker@Green, 14], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[a], {a, i - 3600, i}], 
 PlotRange -> {{i - 3600, i}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 800, 
 ImagePadding -> {{25, 5}, {20, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Axes -> False]}, {"", Style[Text["Time -s"], Bold, Blue, 14]}}, 
 Spacings -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}]
Do[Pause[0.000001]; i = a, {a, 10, 1000000}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Left `FrameTicks` are jumping. Or only I see this? :)

Comment: @P.Fonseca And Kuba this left `FrameTicks` is driving me crazy... I think this must be a bug, as I've tried almost everything I could but the problem still persists... :-(